# Unable to install PIP for python on windows 8 pc

Tags: python, windows, pip, python-3.2

I have python 3.2 on my pc and i want to be able to run the following:
'pip install requests' and 'pip install selenium'.

To do this i know i need to install pip from here -> https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

But when I click on the file python comes up and closes again right away and pip is not installed.

I tried running it through IDLE and get the following:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jarratt\Desktop\get-pip.py", line 17759, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Jarratt\Desktop\get-pip.py", line 162, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "C:\Users\Jarratt\Desktop\get-pip.py", line 110, in bootstrap
    import setuptools  # noqa
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-19.2-py3.2.egg\setuptools\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from setuptools.extension import Extension
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-19.2-py3.2.egg\setuptools\extension.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-19.2-py3.2.egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-19.2-py3.2.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 106, in <module>
    warnings.warn(msg)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 59, in idle_showwarning
    file.write(warnings.formatwarning(message, category, filename,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
>>>
```

[image]

Comment: pip.exe is a command-line program, not something you run from Python's interactive shell. It should have been installed as `C:\Python32\Scripts\pip.exe`. You can add the `C:\Python32\Scripts` directory to the `PATH` environment variable, or instead use `python -m pip`.

Comment: BTW, 3.2 is ancient. Even 3.4 is no longer getting bug fixes. Seriously consider upgrading.

Comment: Good idea to use latest Python if you don't have legacy code, and starting with Python 3.4 you'll get `pip` "pre-installed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run it from the command line:

1. Download https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py save somewhere so that you could find it like "`C:\`".
2. Open "Start Menu" and in execute type "`cmd`" and `[Enter]`, or search for "`Standard`" folder in "`Start Menu`" and open "`Command line`" there.
3. In command line type and execute "`python C:\get-pip.py`" or "`python3 C:\get-pip.py`".

Usually works fine this way.

Comment: I have done the above and says already installed - i have added a screen shot of the error

Comment: `pip` is separate program you don't need to run it from interactive Python prompt or IDLE. As show in your screenshot, try running "`C:\python32\lib\site-packages\pip`" so i.e. "`C:\python32\lib\site-packages\pip requests`". If it'll work just add "`C:\python32\lib\site-packages`" to your PATH system variable in Windows settings.

Comment: The normal way to run a module directly is via -m, i.e. `python -m pip`. Please do NOT add site-packages to the system `PATH`. Most modules under Lib are not designed to be run as scripts, and this directory should not be on `PATH`. The directory to add to `PATH` is `Scripts`.

Comment: I suggested to add `site-packages` to `PATH`, not to run python modules this way, but to run `pip`, since in screenshot it says that `pip` is in `site-packeges`. **eryksun**, if `pip` is in `Scripts` on a particular machine, then you're right it's a good idea to add `Scripts` to `PATH` and not `site-packages`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are new to python, But pip.exe is a command
and you have to run it from command line, or with run, or by manually clicking on it's icon. You can use this code if you want to:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system("pip")
```